# Error while connecting to AWS RDS from EKS pod

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to reach my AWS RDS instance from within EKS pod. Typically I'm using `telnet` in order to check first if the connection can be established.

`telnet [RDS_ENDPOINT] 5432`

It is returning `Connected to [RDS_ENDPOINT]`.

But when I'm trying to connect via `psql` then I'm getting:

```
psql: error: connection to server at [RDS_ENDPOINT], port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Also, I do can connect from another instance (that was actually the reason I've started to suspect that it might be network issue, but `telnet` seems to say the opposite I guess).

Additional info is that I'm trying to use exactly the same version of psql as my postgres version is, ie. 12.10.

How can I solve this?

[EDIT] Running `pg_isready` gives me `no response` message

Comment: Can you show the arguments you're passing to psql?

Comment: Yes, it is only -U user and I add dB name at the end of the command. For host I use -h

Comment: Look in the db server's log to see what error is reported there.

Comment: After doing the telnet, send a few characters.  What happens?

Comment: After around 2s telnet is closed, connection is shut

Comment: Found the issue, because RDS was in different VPC and I had VPC peering I thought that everything is fine. But reachibility analyzer showed that actually I was missing one route in the route table (for vpc peering).